# MySQL 5.7 workbench 6.2 and 6.3 cannot create users or databases

Tags: mysql, addition, workbench

When I try to add users or databases I get this error in workbench. 
Also if I click on the root user I get this error and I cannot access the privileges.

I have created a database using SQL Query, but from the UI it fails every time.
Previously I have tried with MySQL 5.6 and Workbench 6.2 and I get the same error. The server is running ok and the root login is succesful. The error appeared after I have added a new user and the removed it because the apply button returned an error.

[image]